Proving a certain inequality using Jensen/Tangent line trick
This is from an Olympiad handout about inequalities. It goes as follows:
Let $a\ge b \ge 1$ be two real numbers. Show that
\begin{align}
\frac{a}{\sqrt{a+b}}+\frac{b}{\sqrt{b+1}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{a+1}} \ge 
\frac{b}{\sqrt{a+b}}+\frac{a}{\sqrt{a+1}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{b+1}}.
\end{align}
The inequality is to be proven using the techniques from the title. I've tried to rewrite the inequality in all sorts of ways but with little success. The furthest I've gotten is this:
\begin{align}
2\left( \frac{a}{\sqrt{a+b}}+\frac{b}{\sqrt{b+1}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{a+1}} \right) \ge \sqrt{a+b}+\sqrt{a+1}+\sqrt{b+1}.
\end{align}
Any help would be appreciated.

Hint: motivated by symmetry, we first reorganize the inequality in the following form
\begin{align*}
& \frac{a-b}{\sqrt{a+b}} + \frac{b-1}{\sqrt{b+1}} + \frac{1 - a}{\sqrt{1 + a}} \ge 0 \\
\Leftrightarrow & \frac{(a-1) + (1-b)}{\sqrt{a+b}} + \frac{b-1}{\sqrt{b+1}} + \frac{1 - a}{\sqrt{1 + a}} \ge 0 \\
\Leftrightarrow & (a-1) \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{a+b}} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{a+1}}\right) + (b-1) \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{b+1}} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{a+b}}\right) \ge 0
\end{align*}
Consider the first bracket
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{a+b}} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{a+1}}.$$
Consider $f_a(x) := \frac{1}{a+x}$.

Check that $f_a(x)$ is a convex function.
The first bracket is $f_a(b) - f_a(1)$. Convexity of $f_a(x)$ gives you a lower bound of $f_a(b) - f_a(1)$ in terms of $b-1$. Write down this lower bound explicitly.

Now do the similar thing for the second bracket,
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{b+1}} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{a+b}}.$$
(This time, find a lower bound in terms of $a - 1$.) This should prove the inequality.

The desired inequality is written as
$$\frac{a}{\sqrt{a+b}}+\left(\frac{a}{\sqrt{b+1}} - \frac{a -b}{\sqrt{b+1}}\right)+\frac{1}{\sqrt{a+1}} \ge 
\frac{b}{\sqrt{a+b}}+\frac{a}{\sqrt{a+1}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{b+1}},$$
or
$$\frac{a}{\sqrt{b+1}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{a+1}} - \frac{a}{\sqrt{a+1}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{b+1}}\ge 
\frac{a -b}{\sqrt{b+1}} - \frac{a-b}{\sqrt{a+b}},$$
or
$$(a - 1)\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{b+1}} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{a+1}}\right) \ge 
(a - b)\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{b+1}} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{a+b}}\right),$$
or
$$(a-1)\frac{\sqrt{a+1}-\sqrt{b+1}}{\sqrt{b+1}\sqrt{a+1}}
\ge (a- b)\frac{\sqrt{a+b}-\sqrt{b+1}}{\sqrt{b+1}\sqrt{a+b}},$$
or
$$\frac{(a-1)(a-b)}{\sqrt{b+1}\sqrt{a+1}(\sqrt{a+1}+\sqrt{b+1})}
\ge \frac{(a-1)(a-b)}{\sqrt{b+1}\sqrt{a+b}(\sqrt{a+b}+\sqrt{b+1})},$$
which is true since
$$\sqrt{b+1}\sqrt{a+1}(\sqrt{a+1}+\sqrt{b+1})
\le \sqrt{b+1}\sqrt{a+b}(\sqrt{a+b}+\sqrt{b+1}).$$
We are done.
